# Can't understand generic repository pattern in asp.net documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am begginer. Can't understand an argument in `GetAll()` method in asp.net repository pattern documentation  [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

            if(filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            if(includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach (var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProp);
                }
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            return query.ToList();
        }
```

I  can't understand `Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy`. please explain this arguments and pass parameter to this method.

there is also an example of passing data  `q => q.OrderBy(s => s.LastName)` but it is not enough for me to understand, would you please give more example

Comment: What is the problem with that `Func<T,TResult>` argument?

Comment: i don't understand how to use this agrument , which data should i pass? how should  i pass arguments,

Comment: `GetAll<User>(x => x.IsActive, query => query.OrderBy(u => u.Name));`

Comment: relevant https://bigmachine.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/     for example this signature does not allow for `Skip` and `Take()` so Paging will be done in client.

Comment: But you already know how the common `Func<T,TResult>` is working?

Comment: You can't understand the article because it's really, really bad, written for DDD-like fashion appeal. A DbContext is *already* a multi-entity Unit-of-Work and repository, a DbSet is already a generic single entity repository. All the methods in the articles *non*-generic repositories work simply because they're shortcuts to DbContext calls or LINQ queries. The "generic" one only makes life a *lot* harder than just writing the LINQ query while offering nothing useful. Certainly none of the DDD benefits

Comment: Check Rob Connery's [Repositories and Unit Of Work Don't mix](https://robconery.com/databases/repositories-on-top-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/). The article explains the problem with "repositories" and shows the *correct* way if you really care about DDD - Command/Query separation *without* requiring a "generic" repository put on top of the high-level UoW/DbContext

Comment: @Firo Most examples are not feature complete and are reduced to the bare minimum. But when you have understood this example, then it is a very easy step to add pagination

Comment: @SirRufo I know but why do it in the first place? Panagiotis Kanavos linking to  the same Article like me points out that it is a useless abstraction. And most beginners do not *re*implement the missing features correctly and end up with performance problems after deployment.